# Validating a number in a textbox [VB2010]

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a part of an application for a movie ticket program.

Basically, I have to write an If statement verifying the age put in a textbox, based on a radiobox that is checked.

So, if the radiobox "PG" is checked, the age in the textbox has to be equal to or greater than 12. If "Restricted" is checked, then the textbox has to be equal to or great than 17.

Can anyone help me out with this? I'd appreciate it a lot.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the assumption that this is an asp.net app?

If that's the case, the best approach is to make the radio button and the text postback by setting its Autopostback property to true.  On server-side, check the combination and act accordingly.

Use a Switch statement to check the age based on the rating selected.

You could wrap these in an UpdatePanel to prevent visible post-back.

psuedo code:

```
rating_changed() {
   checkAge();
}

txtAge_changed() {
  checkAge();
}

void checkAge() {
  bool ageOkay = false;
  int age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);

  switch (rating.SelectedItem.Value) {
     case "G":
        ageOkay = true;
        break;
     case "PG":
        if (age >= 8) ageOkay = true;
        break;
     case "PG-13":
        if (age >= 13) ageOkay = true;
        break;
  } 

if (ageOkay) {
  //do next task
} else {
  //you're not old enough
}
}
```